# Spring combination in series and parallel

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

I know the equivalent formula for spring constant for springs connected in parallel and series. But how do I identify whether those are in series or parallel?

Answer (score 2):

In the same way that resistors in series are connected together and have the same current passing through them, springs in series have the same force acting on them and resistors in parallel are connected together and have the same potential difference across them, springs in parallel extend by the same amount.

Comment: https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2Fbae%2Fbaeb735c-93c7-4461-a135-e9877fdde372%2Fphp6RBkde.png Please comment on this image whether this one is in parallel or series...

Comment: @DevanshuPandey The force exerted on/by each spring is the same. The complication is that the total extension of the springs is not the distance moved by the load attached to the pulley.